# Freeze redirect in cypress

Tags: testing, redirect, cypress, end-to-end, google-analytics-4

I would like to test a GA4 product click event. For this I write the required data in the data layer and I want to see if the correct data is in the data layer. However, when I click on the product in Cypress, the redirect is faster than the test can read the data layer. Is there any way I can pause or freeze the redirect?

Here the expectet data in the Datalayer:

```js
                select_item: {
                    event: 'select_item',
                    ecommerce: {
                        item_name: 'Artiklename',
                        item_id: '000000',
                        price: 1.19,
                        currency: 'EUR',
                        item_brand: 'Brand',
                        item_category: 'category',
                        item_category2: 'category2',
                        item_category3: 'category3',
                        item_category4: 'category4',
                        index: 1,
                        quantity: 1,
                        item_list_name: "List Name"
                    },
                },
```

Here the actual Test:

```js
context('Google Analytics 4: should track select_item event', function () {
    it('should track select item on search page', function () {
        cy.getTrackingData('expressShippingArticle', 'select_item').then(
            (expectedSelectItemEvent) => {

                // act
                cy.visitWithBasicAuth(
                    routes.category.resultList(
                        '000/SomeArticle'
                    )
                )
                
                //assert
                cy.getSpecificEventFromDataLayer('select_item').then(
                    (event) => {
                        cy.wrap(event).should('not.exist')
                    }
                )
                
                // act
                cy.get(selectors.resultList.productInResultList)
                    .first()
                    .click()
                
                cy.getSpecificEventFromDataLayer('select_item').then(
                    (actualSelectItemEvent) => {
                        cy.wrap(actualSelectItemEvent, { timeout: 0 }).should(
                            spok(expectedSelectItemEvent)
                        )
                    }
                )
            }
        )
    })    
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this works with GA4, but if you want to delay a network request/response add an intercept with delay option

```js
cy.intercept(redirect-url, (req) => {
  req.reply(res => {
    res.setDelay(2000)
  })
})

// act
cy.get(selectors.resultList.productInResultList).first().click()
...
```

Comment: Hey thanks for the answer, it doesn't work that way initially, but I'll try to build something around there, maybe I can work it out with your Idea